OpenSSL Signing Errors due to configuration file and crypto/bio/bss_file
I've been struggling with creating an intermediate certificate authority on Windows 10/11 and using it to sign a non-OCSP end instrument certificate.
The root CA can create and sign an end-instrument certificate. But the intermediate CA fails each time.
I'm retracing my steps, however now I cannot even successfully sign an intermediate CA CSR.
The environment variables are set as follows:
User Variables
Variable Path
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
System Variables
Variable Name: OPENSSL_CONF
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\root\ca\openssl.cnf
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate>openssl genrsa -out private\intermediate.key.pem 4096
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
.................................................................++++
..................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)

C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate>openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -sha256 -key private\intermediate.key.pem -out csr\intermediate.csr.pem
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Common Name []:IntermediateCA
Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:US
State or Province Name [MyState]:Hidden
Locality Name []:Hidden
Organization Name [MyOrg]:Hidden
Organizational Unit Name []:
Email Address []:

C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate>openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 -in csr\intermediate.csr.pem -out certs\intermediate.cert.pem
Using configuration from openssl.cnf
ootcaintermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem for reading, Invalid argument
ootcaintermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem','r')or:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('C:Program FilesOpenSSL-Win64
3880:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:78:
unable to load CA private key

C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate>

For clarity, below are all of the commands used.
CREATNG ROOT DIRECTORY:
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64"
mkdir root\ca
mkdir certs crl newcerts private
echo 01 > serial
type NUL > index.txt

GENERATING ROOT KEY:
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca"
openssl genrsa -out private\root.key.pem 4096

GENERATING ROOT CERTIFICATE:
openssl req -config "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64"\root\ca\openssl.cnf" -key private\ca.key.pem -new -x509 -days 7300 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -out certs\ca.cert.pem

CREATNG INTERMEDIATE DIRECTORY:
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca"
mkdir intermediate\ca
mkdir certs crl csr newcerts private
echo 01 > serial
type NUL > index.txt
echo 01 > crlnumber

GENERATING INTERMEDIATE KEY:
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate"
openssl genrsa -out private\intermediate.key.pem 4096

GENERATING CSR:
openssl req -config "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\openssl.cnf" -new -sha256 -key private\intermediate.key.pem -out csr\intermediate.csr.pem

SIGNING CSR WITH INTERMEDIATE KEY:
openssl ca -config "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\openssl.cnf" -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 -in csr\intermediate.csr.pem -out certs\intermediate.cert.pem

For reference, below are my Root and Intermediate OpenSSL.CNF files.
# OpenSSL root CA configuration file.
# Copy to `/root/ca/openssl.cnf`.

[ ca ]
# `man ca`
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
# Directory and file locations.
certs             = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/certs
crl_dir           = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/crl
new_certs_dir     = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/newcerts
database          = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/index.txt
serial            = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/serial
RANDFILE          = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/private/.rand

# The root key and root certificate.
private_key       = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/private/ca.key.pem
certificate       = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/certs/ca.cert.pem

# For certificate revocation lists.
crlnumber         = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/crlnumber
crl               = C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/root/ca/certs/ca.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 30

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md        = sha256

name_opt          = ca_default
cert_opt          = ca_default
default_days      = 375
preserve          = no
policy            = policy_strict

[ policy_strict ]
# The root CA should only sign intermediate certificates that match.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of `man ca`.
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ policy_loose ]
# Allow the intermediate CA to sign a more diverse range of certificates.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of the `ca` man page.
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
# Options for the `req` tool (`man req`).
default_bits        = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask         = utf8only

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md          = sha256

# Extension to add when the -x509 option is used.
x509_extensions     = v3_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request>.
commonName                      = Common Name
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default             = XX
stateOrProvinceName_default     = MyState
localityName_default            =
0.organizationName_default      = MyOrg
organizationalUnitName_default  =
emailAddress_default            =

[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ usr_cert ]
# Extensions for client certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client, email
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, emailProtection

[ server_cert ]
# Extensions for server certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

[ crl_ext ]
# Extension for CRLs (`man x509v3_config`).
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ ocsp ]
# Extension for OCSP signing certificates (`man ocsp`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning

# OpenSSL intermediate CA configuration file.
# Copy to `/root/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf`.

[ ca ]
# `man ca`
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
# Directory and file locations.
certs             = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\certs
new_certs         = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\newcerts
new_certs_dir     = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\newcerts
database          = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\index.txt
serial            = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\serial
RANDFILE          = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\private\.rand

# The root key and root certificate.
private_key       = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\private\ca.key.pem
certificate       = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\certs\ca.cert.pem

# For certificate revocation lists.
crlnumber         = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\crlnumber
crl               = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\root\ca\intermediate\intermediate.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 30

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md        = sha256

name_opt          = ca_default
cert_opt          = ca_default
default_days      = 375
preserve          = no
policy            = policy_loose

copy_extensions   = copy

[ policy_strict ]
# The root CA should only sign intermediate certificates that match.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of `man ca`.
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ policy_loose ]
# Allow the intermediate CA to sign a more diverse range of certificates.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of the `ca` man page.
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
# Options for the `req` tool (`man req`).
default_bits        = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask         = utf8only

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md          = sha256

# Extension to add when the -x509 option is used.
x509_extensions     = v3_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request>.
commonName                      = Common Name
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default             = XX
stateOrProvinceName_default     = MyState
localityName_default            =
0.organizationName_default      = MyOrg
organizationalUnitName_default  =
emailAddress_default            =

[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ usr_cert ]
# Extensions for client certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client, email
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, emailProtection

[ server_cert ]
# Extensions for server certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
authorityInfoAccess = OCSP;URI:http://ocsp2.example.com
#subjectAltName = @alt_names

#[ alt_names ]
#DNS.1 = example.com
#DNS.2 = www.example.com
#DNS.3 = m.example.com

[ crl_ext ]
# Extension for CRLs (`man x509v3_config`).
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ ocsp ]
# Extension for OCSP signing certificates (`man ocsp`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning

I have attempted this process on Win 10 and Win 11 with zero success and I have removed and reinstalled the OpenSSL executable from Shining Light Productions
The crypto bio file error also seems to be identical to the error I used to encounter with signing the end instrument certificate with the intermediate CA.
